# three c# concurrent queue's - how can I pause them while a particular action needs to happen?

Tags: c#, winforms, locking, queue

I have a question, and I could do with some code examples to help me, and I feel it may help to give some background.

I have the need to create an engine of 3 Queues (in C#, winforms). The 3 Queues merely contain an "action" object. Actions get thrown into the engine, and stick themselves to the "most available" Queue (basically, the Queue with the lowest count). Almost all of the time the Queues can run discretely and asynchronously with no harm. However there is one "Action" situation which may happen, and when that type of "Action" occurs and does bubble to the front of a Queue, it must :

- wait for the other queues to stop their current actions
- lock/pause them when they are finished on their current Action
- run the Action alone until it finishes
- release the lock on the other 2 queues.

With the added issue that any of the 3 queues can lock the other 2.

Does anyone have any experience of this?

I hope so, it seems a bit painful :-) Thanks in advance

Comment: There's one missing piece of important information here: those SpecialActions - how many of them can be at once registered in the queue? is it singular occurence that happens once in some time and you are guaranteed that a new SpecialAction will not come until the current one is resolved (if this is true, then SpecialActions does not have to be put into the queues!)? Or maybe there may be 100 of those SpecialAction stored in the queues and all of them, one after another, have to halt everything and resolve, one at time (if this is true, what should be the order of running them)?

Comment: Quetzalcoatl it's a good question. The actions are these four. 1) copy file from server 2) copy file to server 3) delete local file 4) rehash value a file. The Special action is file rehash, and it's fairly common (yet fast), the event that causes it is a file change event. However the hash table is a look up table for all the other 3 hence the pause

Comment: @conners: I've posted my suggestion based on the other two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a combination of the [single queue approach recommended by Servy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13369824/56778) and the [`ReaderWriterLock` suggestion by Casperah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13369801/56778).

```
ReaderWriterLockSlim throttler = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
for (int i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        foreach (Action nextAction in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            if (mustBeExectutedSerially(nextAction))
            {
                try
                {
                    throttler.EnterWriteLock();
                    nextAction();
                }
                finally
                {
                    throttler.ExitWriteLock();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    throttler.EnterReadLock();
                    nextAction();
                }
                finally
                {
                    throttler.ExitReadLock();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your read/write locks are reversed; either that or you should just rename the function that returns a boolean to something like `canExecuteInParallel`.

Answer (score 3):

First off, I wouldn't suggest using three queues.  I'd suggest using one queue and just have 3 different tasks reading from it.  I'd also suggest using `BlockingCollection<T>` (which is just a wrapper for a `ConcurrentQueue` as it's easier to work with.

As for the rest, a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` ([Thanks Casperah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13369801/1159478)) should handle it easy enough.  A Writer requires an exclusive lock, and a reader only locks out other writers, which is exactly your use case.

```
var queue = new BlockingCollection<Action>();

int numWorkers = 3;
ReaderWriterLockSlim throttler = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();


for (int i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        foreach (Action nextAction in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            if (mustBeExectutedSerially(nextAction))
            {
                try
                {
                    throttler.EnterWriteLock();
                    nextAction();
                }
                finally
                {
                    throttler.ExitWriteLock();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    throttler.EnterReadLock();
                    nextAction();
                }
                finally
                {
                    throttler.ExitReadLock();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Servy, I'll post you the answer, it's not that the other answers were wrong (they all had merit - so thanks everyone!) but yours was the most flexible (changing queue number is something I'll probably use) and the most concise

Comment: +1 for the single-queue suggestion. Very often it results in a tiny bit of more waiting, but much less idleness of the workers!

Comment: There is a race condition here that will result in a "deadly embrace". If two workers each dequeue an action that must be executed serially, they will both try to do `numWorkers` waits on the semaphore. At that point, all processing stops because every worker is waiting on the semaphore and no worker will ever do a release.

Comment: @conners: I would suggest using a single queue as outlined here, but use the `ReaderWriterLock` (or, preferably, `ReaderWriterLockSlim`) that was proposed in the other answer.

Comment: @Jim actually I re-read it - I am a little too unsure as to how these 2 solutions combine, can you post something Jim? I've released the "Accept"

Answer (score 2):

It seems that a  System.Threading.ReaderWriterLock will do the job for you.

A normal task should do this:

```
readerWriterLock.AcquireReaderLock(timeout);
try
{
    RunNormalAction();
}
finally
{
     readerWriterLock.ReleaseReaderLock();
}
```

And the advanced task should do this:

```
readerWriterLock.AcquireWriterLock(timeout);
try
{
    RunSpecialAction();
}
finally
{
     readerWriterLock.ReleaseWriterLock();
}
```

You can start as many ReaderLocks as you want, and they will keep running as expected.
When a WriterLock is Acquired all the ReaderLocks has been released and only one WriterLock will run at a time.

Comment: +1, except that I would recommend `System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim` if it's all in a single process (which appears to be the case).

Answer (score 0):

My humble sugestion:

Create three objects

```
object threadlock1 = new object();
object threadlock2 = new object();
object threadlock3 = new object();
```

Each thread acquires lock over one object before running any action.

```
lock (threadlock1)  // On thread 1, for example
{ //Run Action }
```

When THE action comes, the thread with THE action must acquire lock over the three objects, thus waiting for the other threads to finish their work, and preventing them from doing any more.

```
lock (threadlock1)  // On thread 1, for example
{
 lock (threadlock2)
 {
  lock (threadlock3)
  {
    //Run THE Action 
  }
 }
}
```

When THE action is finished, you release all three locks, and all is back to normal, with each thread holding it's own lock, and resuming actions.

Comment: note that this doesn't scale super well to n workers.  You could put them all in a list or other collection though, and then lock on everything in the collection for the special action.

Comment: If you received 2 instances of THE action at the same time/nearly the same time, on 2 different threads, this could deadlock.

Comment: @JMarsch How exactly? If each thread asks for it's own lock, before the others, I don't think they can exchange locks, can they?

Comment: @LMB: if every thread asks for the lock in exactly the same order: 1, 2, 3, then you are ok (so if your code above is followed precisely for every thread, you're ok.  If you ask for your lock before the others, you can deadlock.  Example:  thread 1 grabs lock1, see's it's THE action, and goes for lock2.  Meanwhile, thread 2 has grabbed lock2, and sees that it is another THE action, and goes for lock 1. (thread 1 is waiting for lock 2, thread 2 is waiting for lock 1, it's deadlocked).  One way to avoid that is to always acquire the locks in the same order.

Comment: But if you always acquire the locks in the same order, then you gain no benefit from having multiple threads. You will never have two or more threads doing work concurrently.

Comment: @JimMischel You only acquire all three locks when THE action is on the stack. At this time, he doesn't want multithreading.